# How do you compare two strings in Yacc/Bison?

Tags: c, string, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

We are asked to use FLEX software and write the code in C.
First string is collected from a text file, this is how I did it in LEX:

```
%option noyywrap yylineno
%{
    #define YYSTYPE char *
    #include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[ \t\n]+ {}
"NAZIV" {return _NAZIV;}
"GODINA" {return _GODINA;}
"TIP" {return _TIP;}
"ECTS" {return _ECTS;}
":" {return _DVOTACKA;}
";" {return _SEMICOLON;}
[A-Za-z]+  {yylval=strdup(yytext); return _VRIJEDNOST;}
[0-9]+   {yylval =atoi(yytext); return _BROJ_BODOVA;}
```

So I need to collect a whatever string `[A-Za-z]+` in second to last line.
Now in Yacc I need to increase a counter if the text file says "obavezni" at that spot.
I did it like so when encountering the spot in text file:

```
: _TIP _DVOTACKA _VRIJEDNOST _SEMICOLON
{result=strcmp($3,string);if(result==0) prvi_uslov=1; }
;
```

The string from up there is `char string[]="obavezni";`
This way I get a bunch of warnings about not being able to compare `const * char` and `*char` and that one of the arguments is of type `YYSTYPE`.

I started doing Yacc/Bison yesterday and I have no idea what this means, I just need a simple way to compare a collected value from text file to an existing string, and if they are same counter goes up. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same example, and I've found a solution. The errors go away after typing:

```
#define YYSTYPE char *
```

My code is also a little bit different here:

```
int val = strcmp($8, "obavezni");
if (val == 0){
    if($11 > 5) 
    temp++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The parser produced by Yacc (or whatever Yacc-derivative you are actually using, probably Bison) and the lexical analyser produced by Flex are separate programs; the two tools are not aware of each other. The communication between the two programs (at least in the default case) is through the global variable `yylval`. By default, `yylval` has the type `int`, but this is only very rarely desirable. In most real-life parsing applications, it is necessary to give `yylval` a different type. And it is essential that the parser and the lexical analyser agree on what this type is. This type is called the "semantic type" of the parser; it is used for the semantic values of all grammar symbols in production rules.

The traditional way of changing the semantic type of `yylval` is to (re)define the preprocessor macro `YYSTYPE`. If you do that, you must ensure that the new definition is included in both the parser and the lexical analyser, which means either including it in the prologues of both your `.l` and the `.y` files. You appear to have only done it in your lexer file, with the result that in your parser, the semantic type is the default `int`. The C compiler complains about using `$3` as an argument to `strcmp` because `$3` is an `int`, and that's not a valid argument type for string comparison.

But I advise you not to add the preprocessor definition to your parser as well, although that will work for now. Instead, you should declare the semantic type using a Bison declaration:

```
%define api.value.type { char * }
```

If you do that, Bison will put the declaration into the header file, which you already `#include` into your lexical analyser. That way, the single declaration will guarantee that the type is the same in both the parser and the lexer.